# Using HangFire in Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am using Hangfire as part of an ASP.NET MVC Website.

When I run the site locally, Hangfire works as expected. However, when I run Hangfire in the Production Environment (In Azure as a Web App), I am not able to access the Dashboard nor does it seem like the automatic jobs are running.

I initialize Hangfire entirely from the Status.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder Application)
{
      Application.CreatePerOwinContext<RepositoryManager>((x, y) => new RepositoryManager(new SiteDatabase(), x, y));
      Application.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
      {
           CookieName = "Authentication",
           LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
           AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
           Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
           {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, User, int>(
                     validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                     regenerateIdentityCallback: (Manager, User) => User.GenerateClaimsAsync(Manager),
                     getUserIdCallback: (Claim) => int.Parse(Claim.GetUserId()))
           }
});

Application.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .UseSqlServerStorage("platform_batch", new SqlServerStorageOptions { SchemaName = "dbo" })
    .UseDashboardMetric(SqlServerStorage.ActiveConnections)
    .UseDashboardMetric(SqlServerStorage.TotalConnections)
    .UseDashboardMetric(DashboardMetrics.FailedCount)
    .UseLogProvider<BatchLogProvider>(new BatchLogProvider())
    .UseFilter<AutomaticRetryAttribute>(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });

Application.UseHangfireDashboard("/dashboard/global/batches",
    new DashboardOptions
    {
        AppPath = "/dashboard/global/overview",
        Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter[] { new ContextRootAttribute(), new ContextStatusAttribute(StatusLevel.Owner) },
    });
    Application.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions { ServerName = Global.Property.Deployment.Environment.ToString() });

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<BatchMinute>(x => x.Begin(), Cron.Minutely());
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<BatchDay>(x => x.Begin(), Cron.Daily(2));
}
```

Again, this method works perfectly fine locally and in our staging environment (which runs on IIS), but doesn’t seem to work in our Azure Production Environment. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try adding error logging so you can make sure your configuration code runs properly?

Comment: Hey Mason - I did and it doesn't seem like anything is being displayed.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing is display"? Do you mean that your logging code isn't getting hit? Then you'll need to show how you expect it to get hit. What's going to call this code when your application starts?

Comment: Hey @mason - in production, only Fatal and Error logs from Hangfire are persisted (supposedly) - and I don't see anything.  We will do a release this evening so that we are able to see Info, Warn, Trace and Debug logs as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution:
To enable access use:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = Enumerable.Empty<IDashboardAuthorizationFilter>()
});
```